# Loop a script every x seconds

Tags: loops, powershell

What can I put around my code to make it loop automatically every x seconds, but if the script is cancelled by CTRL+C, to have it ask for input again?

```
    mode con: cols=40 lines=5
    while ($tag -ne "Q"){
    $tag1 = ""
    while (-not ($tag1)) {
    $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag #, IP, or Q to quit'
    }
    if($tag1 -eq "Q"){break}

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

        mode con: cols=80 lines=53

    cls

        sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;

    cls

        start-sleep -seconds 2
*-Need Loop here-*      
    cls

        $CompInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername $tag1;
        $username = $CompInfo.UserName.Split("\")[1]; #Outputs DOMAIN\USER into an array and selects USER to display
        $fullname = ((net user $username /domain | Select-String "Full Name") -replace "Full Name","").Trim(); #Takes the USER and displays the full name

        #get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername c73118 | format-table -Property @{Name="DOMAIN\user";Expression={$_.username}} --> Get w/o variable

        $CompInfo `
        | Format-Table -Autosize -Property `
            @{ Name = "DOMAIN\user"; Expression = { $_.username } },
            @{ Name = "Full Name"; Expression = { $fullname } };
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need it to loop on a timer?  Seems like all the would accomplish is possibly yank it out from under the user while they're typing input.

Comment: Script pulls the name of the user logged in. Want to run a loop to refresh to see when a user logs into a computer if I am assisting them remotely. It does nothing to their input.

Comment: [Start-Sleep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx)

Comment: That's a start thanks. But how do I tell it to go back to the top of the script when I want to loop it?

Comment: So you don't really want to loop the whole script, just the bits after it gets the input?

Comment: Edited my OP to show where I wanted it to loop at.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is to split this into two scripts. Have the first script take in the input of the computer name, and a second script that loops returning the logged in user.

Your code will look like this:

**C:\test\Script1.ps1**

```
mode con: cols=40 lines=5
while ($tag -ne "Q"){
    $tag1 = ""
    while (-not ($tag1)) {
        $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag #, IP, or Q to quit'
    }
    if($tag1 -eq "Q"){break}

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
    mode con: cols=80 lines=53
    cls
    sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;
    cls

    start-sleep -seconds 2

    #Launch Second script
    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -Command `"& C:\Test\Script2.ps1 $tag1`" "

}
```

**C:\test\Script2.ps1**

```
$tag1 = $args[0]

While(1)
{

        $CompInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername $tag1;
        $username = $CompInfo.UserName.Split("\")[1]; #Outputs DOMAIN\USER into an array and selects USER to display
        $fullname = ((net user $username /domain | Select-String "Full Name") -replace "Full Name","").Trim(); #Takes the USER and displays the full name

        #get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername c73118 | format-table -Property @{Name="DOMAIN\user";Expression={$_.username}} --> Get w/o variable

        $CompInfo `
        | Format-Table -Autosize -Property `
            @{ Name = "DOMAIN\user"; Expression = { $_.username } },
            @{ Name = "Full Name"; Expression = { $fullname } };

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
```

When the first script gets the computer name, it launches the second script in another PowerShell window. This means you can let it run, and use Ctrl + C to exit it, while still keeping your original script running in your first PowerShell session.